# Es/N0 calculation on received symbols

Tags: snr, symbol-energy

What is the proper way to calculate the Es/N0 of demodulated and equalized symbols in simulation for BPSK and QPSK? I have seen various examples that include

1. calculating the standard deviation of the received symbols,
2. calculating the square of the absolute value, and
3. incorporating the energy of the transmitted symbols and then calculating the square of the absolute value of the symbols.

Unsurprisingly, all three yield different results. For the purposes of this question, FEC is ignored (i.e., calculation before FEC removed).

Assumptions:

1. AWGN
2. received signal is time and frequency synchronized
3. s∈{±1}  for BPSK and s∈{±1/sqrt(2)} for QPSK and n∼CN(0,1)

Comment: What is the definition of your Es/N0? Differently put, what will you use it for?

Comment: Metric for the confidence in the demodulator, and a comparison to the SNR (AWGN) added in the simulation.

Comment: "Metric for the confidence in the demodulator" is not a definition. From "a comparison to the SNR (AWGN) added in the simulation" I presume that you are assuming your demodulated and equalized BPSK/QPSK symbols be $\alpha s + n \tag{1}$  where $s \in \{\pm1\}$ for BPSK and $s \in \{\pm\frac{1}{\sqrt{2}}\}$ for QPSK and $n \sim \mathcal{CN}(0,1)$. The only parameter to be estimated is $\mid\alpha\mid^2$, and the EsN0 is *defined* as $\mid\alpha\mid^2$, which is a metric for the confidence of the demodulator that assumes its symbols follow (1). More details can be found in MarcusMuller's answer.

Comment: Yes, all of those are correct assumptions for the BPSK and QPSK symbols, and the distribution of the noise.

Comment: can you actually write down a signal model in math, @BigBrownBear00, which incorporates your $s$? it's really confusing what you write here in the comments!

Comment: Sorry - I just don't know how to format math on my posts. This is a textbook BPSK/QPSK signal model, where the received signal r, is r = s + n. 

s is the transmitted BPSK/QPSK symbols, and n is AWGN.

Comment: Ok, but that is unusual – you know the signal strength at the receiver to be 1? You *can* do that, but it basically presumes you know `$E_s/N_0$` before!

Comment: No, signal strength is unknown at the receiver, but because the system has equalization with a known training sequence, the output symbols are scaled based on the known reference sequence.

Comment: but then you already know the signal energy from the preamble, and you know the total signal energy, which is the sum of signal and noise, so, what's the question?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/137722/discussion-between-bigbrownbear00-and-marcus-muller).

Comment: sorry, not a fan of the chat!

Answer (score 1):

Generally: Here, you need to be better at explicitly writing down your channel-, noise and signal models! Being clear in your head about this answers such questions pretty easily. There's no "general" answers; we have to make statements about these things.

---

The transmitted energy is completely irrelevant at the receiver, so not quite sure what you expect 3. to yield – unless you can calculate the received bit energy from that, because you happen to know the channel. You probably would have mentioned that!

So, you're stuck on estimating noise and signal energy from a noisy observation. We know not the noise model you're using – but let's, for the sake of simplicity, assume it's *additive* noise, and it's *uncorrelated* to the signal. (Also, we imply it's got zero mean. This is a technically viable assumption.)

In that case, the received power is the sum of noise power – which is the noise's variance – and the signal power. Calculate the sum energy, subtract one, get the other, divide.

So, the energy in a signal is the sum of magnitudes squares by definition; there's no room for interpretation there.

Estimating the variance of the noise can be done by many means, and which one works for your scenario depends on the channel- and noise model. However, in the simple case of a flat channel, with perfect timing recovery, a simply moment-based estimator works well.

We know that the amplitude of the noiseless reception would be constant for any PSK.

Let's start with BPSK. Assume perfect phase recovery (we can do without, the math gets a bit more involved). That means the only part of the receive signal that changes due to the transmit signal is the real part. So, a noise-free received signal would take one of two values: $+A$ and $-A, \quad A>0$, we don't know the actual value of $A$.

Now, we don't receive noise-free (else, our $E_s/N_0$ would diverge towards $+\infty$ and we'd be done). But: if the noise realization is rarely flipping a positive received signal into the negative, or vice versa, we can just look at the received signal when it's positive, then look at the times when it's negative; we ignore the cases where we actually make an error on decision.

Then, all these cases have the form $A+N$, and $A\,\text{const.}$ means that $\text{Var}(A+N) = \text{Var}(N)$ (variance is shift-invariant). Great! We calculated the noise power (or energy, respectively, if we multiply with the number of samples). Now, subtract that from the overall energy of your receive signal; you get the signal energy, which is $E_S$.

Now, that's valid (and almost only in that case) if the following is all true, and I stress that with my students, when *all* of the following applies:

1. Noise is additive
2. Noise is uncorrelated to signal
3. Noise is zero-mean
4. We have achieved perfect synchronization in time and phase
5. flat channel
6. SNR relatively high, so that the cases where a received signal flips its sign due to noise are rare enough.

As you can see, that's six assumptions that you didn't explicitly make. But we have to make them to arrive at a method that works! So, if these assumptions do not describe what you're dealing with, you'll have to research a more specific question, but having these cornerstones to categorize your scenario might help with that :)

Comment: I clarified with a few assumptions in the original post. Can you explain A+N , and Aconst. means that Var(A+N)=Var(N). What do you mean by A const.?

Comment: "A const." means "A is a constant, not a randomly varying number"

Comment: To make sure I understand, you are saying to calculate the variance of the received demodulated symbols (and this is the noise power), and then subtract that from the received symbols to get Es?

Comment: yes, exactly that.